# Xcode `text` error?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently following Xcode tutorials at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1). I am at finishing the tutorials at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1). So I have a problem while following the tutorials. The problem I have is with my `Add_todo_itemViewController.m`. (Side Note: I am using a different name from the tutorials, they use `AddToDoItemViewController` as the class)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {             //Error here saying that property 'text' is not found
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text; //Error here saying that property 'text' is not found
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}
```

Now here I am getting two errors saying that `'text'` is not defined. I would like it if someone could say what is wrong. If you need more code to find the error, please state that in the comments.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: How you declared `self.textField` ?

Comment: What is the result of `NSLog(@"%@", self.textField);`?

Comment: As a side note: by convention, while developing in Ojbective-C, `AddToDoItemViewController.m` is in correct conventional format, and your format is less conventional. We don't use underscores much in ObjC.

Comment: @MidhunMP I think so...